# check if a function exist after dynamically changing data (after an ajax call)

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have a function which executes on window load

```
<div id="removeItOnAjaxCall">
<script>
    foo = function() {
    // some stuff
    }
</script>
</div>
```

There is also an ajax call which can remove this function from the DOM like.

```
    new Ajax.Updater('chkboxpos, 'myscript.php', {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            $('removeItOnAjaxCall').remove(); //now I don't have foo function in my DOM. but DOM think it is
        }
    });
```

Now if I make a call to this function I got an error

```
element is null
var method = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
```

because the DOM thinks it has that function defined but actually it doesn't have one. I hope I am making it more clear now.

Comment: You cannot "remove a function from the DOM". Functions are not in the DOM to start with. Furthermore, an ajax call cannot remove anything, whether from the DOM or the JS namespace.

Comment: Torazburo, I remove a complete div (using javascript) which also contain that function within it offcurse in script tag on basis of ajax call.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer where do i check your answer?

Comment: i reposted now @yiiframe

Comment: give me a minute, I am updating my question to make my requirement more clear.

Comment: Removing a div does not undefine a function defined in a script tag inside the div. Once the function is defined, it's defined, What makes you think it became undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about how `<script>` tags work. Once a script is encountered and parsed, any definitions inside it are never removed, even if the `script` tag, or its enclosing element, is removed. The only way a function could be undefined is by doing so explicitly, such as `delete window.fun;` or `fun = null`.

Therefore, your concern is misplaced. There is no need to check if the function still exists--it does, no matter what elements you manipulated in your ajax handler. Why did you think the function would become undefined?

The DOM is fundamentally separate from the JS namespace. Functions are not contained in the DOM; they are contained in the JS namespace. The DOM has no idea whatsoever about what functions might exist or not. Nothing you could posssibly do to the DOM could affect JS logic or data. Since functions do not exist in the DOM, they cannot be removed from the DOM. You say

> Now if I make a call to this function I got an error because the DOM thinks it has that function defined but actually it doesn't have one.

With regard to your error:

```
element is null
var method = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
```

this has nothing to do with the function `foo`. Since the element has been removed, it is null. You can't get the `tagName` of a non-existent element. You say you are "making a call to this function", but you're not making a call to that function. You are trying to get the `tagName` of an element, which is an entirely different thing.

Having said that, it seems a bit odd to place a script tag within an element which is maybe going to be removed--why are you doing that?

Comment: updated the question with error I am getting in console.

Comment: Updated my answer to describe why you are getting the error.

Comment: +1 for making my concept more clear on JS namespace and DOM. I was getting that error on calling that function but I was totally wrong, I guess there is something in function definition which causing this error I will get back to you once figure it out and Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = function() {
  // some stuff
 }    
if(typeof foo == "function")){
    console.log("function exist");
}
```

Comment: But how and why would `foo` ever stop being a function after being defined?

Comment: @Swapnil I know how to check if a function exist or not, but after removing it from the `DOM` on basis of `ajax` result. for `DOM` function exist and is defined but actully its not coz `DOM` wouldnt update itself after ajax response